# Replace <pre> without <code> to <pre> <code> once only

Tags: javascript

How to replace just <pre> which is not already wrapping <code>
with <pre><code> using jquery or javascript.

Example:

I have code like:

```
<pre>&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;</pre> <-- Target

<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>
```

I need change only <pre> like this:

```
<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>  <-- Only change this <pre>

<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>
```

Check my problem below site: http://www.webmanajemen.com/p/testting-page.html

Comment: This is very unclear. Are you asking how to modify the contents of a DOM element using Javascript?

Comment: I think the OP wants every <pre> element to have a <code> children.

Comment: I think I fixed the messy logic

Comment: `$("pre:not(:has(code))").each(function() { $(this).wrapInner( "<code></code>") });` https://jsfiddle.net/2jcL6h0w/

Comment: Thank to "Alon Eitan" --> https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan

I have done with my problem using this jquery:

$("pre:not(:has(code))").each(function() { $(this).wrapInner( "<code></code>") });
Check my problem below site: web-development.cf/p/testting-page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to "[Alon Eitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan)".

I have done with my problem using this jquery:

```
$("pre:not(:has(code))").each(function() { $(this).wrapInner( "<code></code>") });
```

Check my problem below site: web-development.cf/p/testting-page.html

Comment: 1: It was not me but Alon, 2: do not answer with someone else code. Instead ask him to answer and accept his answer

Answer (score -1):

Ick.

Regex I guess.

```
function replace(html) {
  return html
    // Look-ahead for <code>
    .replace(/(<pre>)(?!<code>)/gi, '<pre><code>')
    // Look-behind for </code>
    .replace(/(<\/pre>)/gi, function(m, g, i, s) {
      return s.slice(i-7, i) === '</code>'
        ? m
        : '</code></pre>'
      })

}

replace('<pre>&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;</pre>')
// returns "<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>"

replace('<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>') 
// returns "<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;</code></pre>"
```

Answer (score -1):

You question is definitely unclear, but if I understand correctly, you want to basically add a  tag into any  tags that don't already contain .

This can be done by getting all of the  tags, and then looking at its children to see if there is a  tag:

```
function fillInMissingTags(outerTag, innerTag) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(outerTag);
    for(var elementIndex = 0, elementsLength = elements.length; elementIndex < elementsLength; elementIndex++) {
        var element = elements[elementIndex],
            found = false
            html;

        for(var childIndex = 0, childrenLength = element.children.length; childIndex < childrenLength; childIndex++) {
            var child = element.children[childIndex];
            if(child.tagName.toLowerCase() === innerTag) {
                found = true;
                html = element.innerHTML;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found !== true) {
            var codeElement = document.createElement(innerTag);
            codeElement.innerHTML = html;
            element.innerHTML = codeElement;
        }
    }
}

fillInMissingTags('pre', 'code');
```

This would only handle checking for  in the immediate children. If you wanted to do a deep check, you would need to modify it to check the children recursively.

**EDIT**
I made it more generic so you can use the method to wrap the insides of any element that is missing a proper child.